# Single TCP server and multiple clients - server seems to be communicating only with last conected clients

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am using select() function and trying to run multiple clients. Each client is independent process. But the server seems to be interested only in the last connected clients.

These is my client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define PORT 8888

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* Starting the MPI verion from here */

    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of generators to be run in parallel
    int number_of_clients;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &number_of_clients);

    // Get the rank of each generator
    int client_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &client_rank);

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sock = 0, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char *message1 = "Hello from client";
    char *message2 = "I am disconnecting";
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    send(sock , message1 , strlen(message1) , 0 );
    printf("Hello message sent from client_rank %d\n",client_rank);
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);


    buffer[valread] = '\0';
    printf("The message received from server by client_rank %d is %s\n", client_rank, buffer );
    send(sock, message2, strlen(message2), 0);
    printf("The message sent again from client_rank %d is %s\n", client_rank, message2);
    close(sock);
    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
    /*Ending the parallel version here*/

    return 0;
}
```

This is my server.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <unistd.h>   //close 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> //FD_SET, FD_ISSET, FD_ZERO macros 

#define PORT 8888

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int totalconnections = 0;
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address, cli_addr;;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    socklen_t clilen;
    int closed_connections = 0;
    int client_socket[3] , max_clients = 2 , activity, i , sd, max_sd;
    int connected_clients = 0;  
    fd_set readfds;

    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked 
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
    {  
        client_socket[i] = 0;  
    } 

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    // Bind the server to the port and address
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("Binding Error : ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //listen to the connections
    if (listen(server_fd, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("Listen Error : ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1)  
    {  
        //clear the socket set 
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);  

        //add master socket to set 
        FD_SET(server_fd, &readfds);  
        max_sd = server_fd;  

        //add child sockets to set 
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)  
        {  
            //socket descriptor 
            sd = client_socket[i];                 
            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list 
            if(sd > 0)  
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);                  
            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function 
            if(sd > max_sd)  
                max_sd = sd;  
        }      
        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL, so wait indefinitely 
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL); 

        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))  printf("select error"); 

        //If something happened on the master socket ,then its an incoming connection 
        if (FD_ISSET(server_fd, &readfds))  
        {  
            if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)  
            {  
                perror("accept");  
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
            }  

            //Print out the details of the new connection 
            printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d\n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));   

            //add new socket to array of sockets 
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
            {  
                //if position is empty 
                if( client_socket[i] == 0 )  
                {  
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;                         
                    break;  
                }  
            }   
        }  

        //else its some IO operation on some other socket
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
            {  
                sd = client_socket[i];  

                if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))  
                {  
                    //Read the incoming message. If valread = 0, then that client disconnected
                    valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024) ;
                    if(valread == 0) 
                    {  
                        //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print 
                        getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address ,(socklen_t*)&addrlen);  
                        printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" ,inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));  

                        //Increase the closed connection by 1    
                        closed_connections++;  
                        client_socket[i] = 0;  
                    }  

                    //Send message to the client that sent the message
                    else
                    {  

                        buffer[valread] = '\0'; 
                        getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address ,(socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                        printf("Message received from client connected to port %d is %s \n",ntohs(address.sin_port), buffer );
                        send(sd , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
                        printf("Hello message sent to client connected on port %d\n", ntohs(address.sin_port));
                    }  
                }  
            }            
        }

        //If all the clients disconnected then break out of while loop
        if(closed_connections == max_clients) break;
    }
    close(server_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compiling client.c**

```
gcc client.c -o client
```

**Compiling server.c**

```
mpicc server.c -o server
```

When I run the server and client using the command **./client** and **mpirun -np 2 ./client**, I get the following output on the **server side**

```
 New connection , socket fd is 4 , ip is : 127.0.0.1 , port : 57448
    New connection , socket fd is 5 , ip is : 127.0.0.1 , port : 57450
    Message received from client connected to port 57450 is Hello from client 
    Hello message sent to client connected on port 57450
    Message received from client connected to port 57450 is Hello from client 
    Hello message sent to client connected on port 57450
    Host disconnected , ip 127.0.0.1 , port 57448 
    Host disconnected , ip 127.0.0.1 , port 57450
```

The output from **client side** is :

```
Hello message sent from client_rank 0
Hello message sent from client_rank 1
The message received from server by client_rank 0 is Hello from server
The message received from server by client_rank 1 is Hello from server
```

I do not know, why the server does not care about the old client.

The second problem that I also noticed is that the server does not receive the message2 sent from the client even though I have used select() function. I think that since I have used select function , server should track any send or disconnect request sent from the client.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: at the beginning, the client prints this message `"Hello message sent from client_rank %d` but there is no such thing in the output. Please edit your question and double check the output matches your sources.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That is only output from the server.

Comment: `//else its some IO operation on some other socket`. Are you sure you need an `else` here ? you could have events on two kind of sockets.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Tried removing else but the output is the same.

Comment: you either have to send the last '\0' character on the client side, or manually add it on the server side before you can `printf(..., buf)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The message sent from the server is received by the client.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The main problem is that the server seems to be getting and replying only to the last connected client which in my case is client connected through port 57450 because it always replies to the same port number if you see the output of the server.

Comment: well, it happens to work for me, but that is likely because I am lucky. see my previous comment, fix your code and check if it helps. The behavior you observes could be caused by the client crashing when `recv()` or `printf()` a message.

Comment: also note your program does not handle short `send()` and short `recv()`, and that could also be an issue. that being said, why are you mixing MPI and TCP sockets ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet i added  it on my code but it is still the same. Did you run for two client processes?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am converting my serial program to parallel program. Previously the program was written using TCP sockets. I am in a phase to convert it to MPI. Is it bad habit to mix TCP and MPI?

Comment: i ran one and two MPI tasks, same results, it works for me. please update your question with the changes you made.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have update the question. Now I am using buffer[valread] = '\0' in both client and server side but it I dont get the correct result still. Is this what you were talking about.

Comment: You've also added a `getpeername()` call which is clearly not being executed. Otherwise you would also now be getting the correct output. Is this the real code? Are you compiling it?

Comment: @EJP Please see the updated server the output but it still doesnot print the message2

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Where did you change to make it running? Is it some other place than where I have used the terminating character?

Comment: If the code has changed, the output must have changed as well. Your quesiton is not self-consistent.

Comment: TCP doesn't do *messaging*, it does *streams of bytes*. You cannot assume that each call to `read` will match a single call of `send` at the other end. If you want *messaging*, it's up to *you* to implement some kind of convention or framing atop TCP. Also, note that *if* `read` completely fills your buffer you've got a buffer overrun when you `\0` terminate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a race condition in your program.

The client `send()` the second message and then `close()` the socket right away.

On the server side, when a message is read, it is **always** sent back to the client.

That means that `SIGPIPE` can occur if the client `close()` the socket **before** the server (fully) sends its reply.

Answer (score -1):

`address` is always that of the most recently-accepted client. You never set it back to be the address of the client you just read a message from. You could do that, with `getpeername()`, but it would be better just to print the actual socket FDs instead of the port.

The message was always wrong anyway. They aren't connected *to* that port, they are connected *from* that port.

So there is no actual problem #1 here to solve. Just doubly misleading messages.

The second problem you mention is caused by your failure to error-check the `send()` and `recv()` functions. So you have no evidence that they didn't fail, so no reason to expect perfect operation. Try it again with error-checking. Could be interesting.

Comment: the client should print `The message sent again from client_rank 0 is I am disconnecting` but there is no such message, and that is the actual issue.

Comment: Yeah using the getpeername() solved one problem. Now server says that its sending to two different clients. But the server doesnot receive the message2 sent from client. Why is it?

Comment: You never implemented any code to handle messages. You just read and write to streams. If you want to send and receive messages, you need to write code to do that.

Comment: "So there is no actual problem here to solve." is simply incorrect.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It refers to problem #1. Problem #2 was not nearly as prominently stated when I posted this. Arguably there is no actual, properly stated, problem #2 either, in the absence of relevant error-checking.